# How to run selenium scripts in remote server, so that a real browser instance is opened in remote server instead of running in background

Tags: selenium, build, automated-tests, awtrobot

**What am I doing:**
I am trying to run my selenium scripts in a remote machine using a build tool (Urban code build in my case).
I am using Robot class in my selenium scripts .

**Issue:**
When the build is triggered from build tool , the scripts are running in background in the remote server (If I log into remote machine, In the task manager I can see , chrome driver is running in background processes) and the build fails.

**Expected result:**
Instead A browser instance (chrome driver) should be opened in the remote machine and then scripts should be executed so that the Robot class in my scripts works fine.

Help me how do I achieve the expected.

Comment: Whats error your getting ? Are you using Webdriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(<URL>,<CAPABILITY> );

Comment: I am using RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver = new ChromeDriver();   .


With this , chrome driver runs in back ground in remote machine , when I triggered the build and my Robot class methods will fail as there is no real browser is opened

Comment: you should do like: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","XYZ/chromedriver.exe"));                       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: Thanks , That property I have already set up , I think there is something wrong with windows services or how the build tool is triggering scripts in remote machine , I am unable to find it